# Loading 3D model in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, 3d

I'm creating a game application from scratch with xcode for iOS, and I've use the OpenGL Game projet template to create mine.

I've searched a lot in the past few days, but I can't find any tutorials or example as to how I would load 3D model (via .obj files) in my application. I've found some documentation on loading them onto an app with a console script, but I need to do it programmatically.

Any help would be very appreciated

Also, my 3D models are created using blender

Comment: did you find any solution on your problem? if so can you share?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I've dropped the project a while ago due mainly to my huge lack of time and experience with Objective-C. But good luck in your search :)

Answer (score 3):

The future will be here momentarily — [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/), available in OS X since v10.8, will be in iOS 8. It can build and render a scene with COLLADA (.DAE) models directly. No need for third-party tools or code, nothing complicated to learn.

Apple's documentation is pretty good but if you prefer then [other tutorials are available](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2012/08/an-introduction-to-scenekit.html).

Answer (score 1):

[OpensceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/documentation/platform-specifics/ios/23-configuring-cmake-for-ios) has support for iOS and a lot of prebuilt code which can help you develop the game. It supports loading OBJ models.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use an Engine (like [isgl3d](http://isgl3d.com), [nineveh](http://nineveh.gl), [Cocos3D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1274), ...) for creating a 3D game, it will be hard if you use Opengl for a start.

Note: you can search for a list of game engine to choose the suitable one for you game, cause there is a lot of game engine, open-source or paid engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the zip file from [here](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl) and then run ./obj2opengl.pl 3DModel.obj in terminal .It will give you 3DModel.h file as output.

You need to use glDrawArrays  instead of glDrawElements as the .h file contains array.

Answer (score 0):

Obj files are simple to parse and are well described on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file). You should be able to load them in one or 2 hours. But if you want to load the materials you need to invest some more time in your engine and into loading the obj file.