# Start with 3D modeling in IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am new to 3D modeling. I have a request to show 3D model in iPad. I have been reading and searching about this and found some out of date discussion about this, and nothing conclusive. I wish to display 3D (probably .obj file) model so the use will be able rotate it. Can you please give me points where to start. OpenGL? Unity? Cocos? I have read this post:

[Want to display a 3D model on the iPhone: how to get started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413919/want-to-display-a-3d-model-on-the-iphone-how-to-get-started)

But its from 2009, in app development time it is ancient... Maybe there is some thing new in this area.

Comment: If loading .obj files is what you want, you can refer to these more recent questions: [Best way to load a obj file on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497380/best-way-to-load-a-obj-file-on-ios) and [Loading 3D model in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697348/loading-3d-model-in-ios). Loading and displaying 3-D models in general is a pretty broad topic, so you might need to be a little more specific to set this question apart from the many others like it that have come up since the one you point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://nineveh.gl/

For implementing 3d objects in your view.

Comment: That project is not finished and not maintained anymore. You can't apply things such as zoom, for example

Answer (score -1):

here's some links from a little bit of research

[How to convert Blender blend (or obj) file to Qualcom Vuforia .h file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508930/how-to-convert-blender-blend-or-obj-file-to-qualcom-vuforia-h-file/14509789#14509789)

http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=66592

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html

these links provide nice information regarding your post, but as far as i can find, there are no concrete tutorials about doing this. You might need to build a 3D model in another program that you are more familiar with to get the concepts down and then try to mimic it in ios